# Stuck with movement of footer when content size increases

Tags: php, css, xhtml

I am stuck with a problem for quite a while now.I have googled and have tried almost all the responses and none of them has worked..
I have a PHP page which has following layout

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header"/>
<div id="content"/>
<div id=footer/>
</div>
```

Now the contents of the content div comes from Db and usually takes up much more height than browsers window size.

Here is the CSS that I have used

```
#footer { 
    color: #707070; 
    clear: both;

    min-height: 100px;

}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

But when the size of that div increase the footer does not move below it rather the footer is shown in the middle of the content div but 1 layer below it.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you sure that is your complete CSS?

Comment: One way to ensure that is your complete CSS is to look at the code in the Chrome browser - open your page, press F12, elements tab, and then expand the DIV's until you get to your footer - on the right hand panel you'll see the actual CSS being used as well as any inherited ones (which could be your problem)

Comment: Strictly speaking, the <div> element is a non-void/non-empty element in HTML, i.e. it is not meant to self-close. Although <div /> is valid XHTML — due to /> being indicative of a self-closing (or empty) XML element — it's interpreted by common HTML parsers and some validators as an unclosed opening tag, and is therefore invalid HTML 4.01 and HTML5.1.

Comment: As for the no-quotes around footer, that is an html 5+ only thing.

Comment: Also, I don't get any error here: http://jsfiddle.net/mKPKV/

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see is that you have no quotes around name of the ID, you need that.

Second thing is that, if everything you gave us is correct, I need to see your PHP to tell you what is wrong, and at least a screenshot of actual problem to be certain, but I think taht part of your php is loading before the footer and part after so it appears that footer is in the middle.